# How can I have a script that runs when a specified disk s unmounted in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am trying to write a script that when I run it, checks to see if a specified drive is mounted, if it is, then it does nothing and the script continues, otherwise it mounts the disk.

The pseudo code for it is:

```
if dev/disksa1 is mounted at /media/server:
    print ""
else:
    mount dev/disk/sa1 at /media/server
```

The actual code I have done to try and achieve this is. This was recommended in another post:

```
if grep -qs 'MinecraftServer' /media/<username>/MinecraftServer/MinecraftServer; then
    echo "Disk already mounted, server boot will continue"
else
     mount /dev/sda1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer
fi
```

For some reason though, no matter what it always remounts the disk, even if it is already mounted.

Not too sure why this is happening, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you aren't just adding an entry in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because I didn't know that that was possible or that is existed. Would you be able to put an answer explaining how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to see what drives are already mounted, that information is usually updated in `/etc/mtab`. My solution to mount an unmounted drive is:

```
if grep --quiet 'drive_name' /etc/mtab; then
   echo "already mounted"
else
   /bin/mount /path/to/mount/point
fi
```

Of course, the mount must already be listed in `/etc/fstab` for `/bin/mount` to work in this fashion.

So, in your specific case, I would suggest:

```
if grep -qs 'MinecraftServer' /etc/mtab; then
    echo "Disk already mounted, server boot will continue"
else
     mount /dev/sda1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux distros (as well as the `mount(8)` command) look for a file called `/etc/fstab` for information on filesystems that should be mounted. Adding an entry in there with the correct options will cause the system to mount the filesystem on boot. See the `fstab(5)` man page for details.

Comment: So if I put the correct code in that file then it will automatically mount the HDD to a location of my choice? If so, where can I find the code to do that, or would you be able to explain how to write it?

Comment: Examine the existing entries, and read the `fstab(5)` man page for details.

Comment: After trying my best to follow the format, I came up with this: `/dev/sdc1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer/ ext4 auto  0 0`. When I restart though, it still does not mount. Do you know why?

Comment: The device node was incorrect, my stupidity. I recently swapped two HDDs so got confused when looking at the names. This works now though. Thank you.